# Strange system hang after SLES12 SP1 installation: Timed out waiting for device

Tags: sles

We'd met a very strange system hang after SLES12 SP1 installation on our device:

Install SLES12SP1 on the device, and after the installation process, when the the device reboots from disk, the system will stuck.

The console print as follow:
  " [ OK ] Started Create static device nodes in /dev.

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-131...abf7168.device.v-disk-by\x2du...(5s / 1min 30s) 

[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/grub2/i386-pc. 

[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems. 

[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Postfix Mail Transport Agent."
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!